# Does there exist a projective module over $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ which is not free?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, projective-module

I know that *finitely generated* projective modules over $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ are free does this result hold for any projective module?

> Does there exist a projective module over $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ which is not free?

Comment: I think this is a corollary of the Theorem 4.3 from [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1255637479) of Bass.

Comment: @spohreis Bass' theorem shows that all projective modules over $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ are free. What do you want more then this?

Comment: Please add this as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

A CW answer to remove this from the unanswered list: All projective modules are free; this is the main result of [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1255637479) by Hyman Bass.

Comment: According to the paper, shouldn't the answer to the question in the title be 'no'?, i.e. non-f.g. projectives over polynomials rings *are* free?

Comment: Edited, thanks!